# Bash behaves weird when PS1 contains wide unicode characters

Tags: bash, prompt, unicode

I'm trying to customize the bash prompt and here is my PROMPT_COMMAND

```
prompt_command() {
  local time="${BLUE}\t${RESET}"
  local user="${GREEN}\u${RESET}"
  local hostname="${GREEN}\H${RESET}"
  local current_dir="${YELLOW}\w${RESET}"

  PS1="⌂ ${time} ${user}@${hostname} ${current_dir} \n ➤ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

And when I try to type something (let it be `whoami`) it looks like bash determines position of the cursor incorrectly. I almost don't see the last (rightmost) symbol (`i` in this example) i.e the cursor overlaps it.

I said "wide" because when I replace `➤` with one of `$`, `ш`, `⌂` symbols everything is OK. I tried another arrows from [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/) with the same result.

Could anyone explain what's happening (or just give me "bash-compatible" arrow) please?

Comment: Bash is completely innocent here; it does not even have the slightest idea of character width. That's your terminal emulator which (out of the goodness of its little heart) allows the use of non-monospace fallback fonts. Use your favorite character map application and choose a character which is actually present in the font selected for the terminal emulator.

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, if it works with another multi byte character, it is a bug in the terminal and not in bash.

Comment: @AlexP, thank you, but I figured out that the problem has nothing to do with fonts (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem was a bit more complicated. The real problem was that I defined my colors like that:

```
[ -z "$TPUT" ] && TPUT=tput
RESET="$(     $TPUT sgr0)"    # Reset all attributes
BRIGHT="$(    $TPUT bold)"    # Set “bright” attribute
BLACK="$(     $TPUT setaf 0)" # foreground to color #0 - black
RED="$(       $TPUT setaf 1)" # foreground to color #1 - red
GREEN="$(     $TPUT setaf 2)" # foreground to color #2 - green
YELLOW="$(    $TPUT setaf 3)" # foreground to color #3 - yellow
BLUE="$(      $TPUT setaf 4)" # foreground to color #4 - blue
MAGENTA="$(   $TPUT setaf 5)" # foreground to color #5 - magenta
CYAN="$(      $TPUT setaf 6)" # foreground to color #6 - cyan
WHITE="$(     $TPUT setaf 7)" # foreground to color #7 - white
FGDEFAULT="$( $TPUT setaf 9)" # default foreground color
export RESET BRIGHT BLACK RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE FGDEFAULT
```

But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004306/ubuntu-bashrc-custom-ps1-behaving-strange#26004434) all the color sequences inside the `PS1` line must be enclosed within `\[` `\]` (I woudn't even think it has something to do with my case but I discovered the same history-overlapping effect as mentioned in that question).

So I changed my colors:

```
[ -z "$TPUT" ] && TPUT=tput
RESET_ESC="\[$(     $TPUT sgr0)\]"
BRIGHT_ESC="\[$(    $TPUT bold)\]"
BLACK_ESC="\[$(     $TPUT setaf 0)\]"
RED_ESC="\[$(       $TPUT setaf 1)\]"
GREEN_ESC="\[$(     $TPUT setaf 2)\]"
YELLOW_ESC="\[$(    $TPUT setaf 3)\]"
BLUE_ESC="\[$(      $TPUT setaf 4)\]"
MAGENTA_ESC="\[$(   $TPUT setaf 5)\]"
CYAN_ESC="\[$(      $TPUT setaf 6)\]"
WHITE_ESC="\[$(     $TPUT setaf 7)\]"
FGDEFAULT_ESC="\[$( $TPUT setaf 9)\]"
```

And the problem (both problems) are gone.

Comment: Well I didn't use colors in PS1 -- but did use the U+2693 ⚓ character, and still got the same problem. There's a relevant (I believe) thread over here https://stackoverflow.com/q/23526353/531179

Comment: Another related hack which solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112774/how-to-escape-unicode-characters-in-bash-prompt-correctly